# How best to do in this situation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optimization, models, polymorphic-associations

I have tree model Meeting , Client, Contact.

When i create new meeting, i can select client or contact , but how better store this structure and association? !Use case  client_id and contact_id in meeting table not good.

Answer (score 1):

We assume someone (a creator) can create a meeting. The creator may be a client or a contact.

For that you need a "creator_type" and "creator_id" column on your Meetings Table first, so add an migration using `script/rails generate migration AddTypeToMeetings`

Then edit the migration file like:

```
class AddTypeToMeetings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column  :meetings, :creator_id, :integer
    add_column  :meetings, :creator_type, :string
  end
end
```

Second, you have to adapt your models:

**meeting.rb**

```
class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  # polymorphic association
  belongs_to  :creator, :polymorphic => true

end
```

**client.rb**

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :meetings, :as => :creator
end
```

**contact.rb**

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :meetings, :as => :creator
end
```

How to use:

```
@my_meeting = Meeting.new

@my_meeting.creator = @my_client
# or if you want a contact:
@my_meeting.creator = @my_contact
```

You can read more up on polymorphic associations here:

- [ASCII Casts](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association)
- [Documentation (scroll to Polymorphic Association)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: Simon thank for your answer, but how can i store "id" this object: client or contact ?!creator_type be saved only type yeah?

Comment: The creator_type saves the class name as far as I know but you could do this: `@my_meeting.creator.is_a?(Client)` or `@my_meeting.creator_is_a?(Contact)`

Comment: Sorry, you need a `creator_id` column too. I've edited my answer ;)